# Слайдер изображений из системных файлов в Android

Tags: android, изображения, slider, adapter

Задача такая: необходимо реализовать слайдер на android,используя изображения, которые хранятся в системных папках андроида. Получение файлов из системы я реализовал,далее нашел готовую библиотеку со слайдером,подключил, но в туториале к [библиотеке](http://marvinlabs.github.io/android-slideshow-widget/) такой код:

```
    adapter = new ResourceBitmapAdapter(this, new int[]{
        R.raw.slide_01, R.raw.slide_02, R.raw.slide_03, R.raw.slide_04});
```

В адаптере создается массив,в который помещаются ресурсы,но у меня то изображения берутся из системных папок. В общем,как в адаптер запхнуть путь к системным изображениям на телефоне?

Comment: посмотрите исходники библиотеки, там есть адаптер и для обычных битмепов. Например `BitmapAdapter.java`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее надо просто пробежаться по папке, где лежит системный `drawable`

```
Field[] drawables = android.R.drawable.class.getFields();
for (Field field : drawables) {
    try {
        list.add(field.getInt(null)); //создайте список и кладите в него интовое значение ресурса
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```